# Copyright and HTML file

Tags: html

I would like to put copyright information in the source of my HTML page. Are there any standardized approaches for doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to know if there is a standard way to embed your copyright information in HTML for search engines and applications, not just *where* and how write them for your users.

If you're using [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) the answer is **yes** there is a standard way: you can use [microdata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microdata_%28HTML%29) to decorate your copyright information and let them be accessible and searchable. For an example take a look at the [AboutPage](http://schema.org/AboutPage) schema on [schema.org](http://schema.org).

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would be to place them in the footer at the bottom of the page, encapsulated with `small` tags

Answer (score 0):

Well, the copyright symbol © is `&copy;`, but aside from that just write something. Typically the symbol, year and name.